# scala repl loses TAB auto-complete after I pause it with ^Z (on linux). can i get auto-complete back?

Tags: scala, shell, read-eval-print-loop

In either spark-shell, or scala repl, when I pop out (via control-Z) to do a shell command I find that auto-complete no longer works when i come back to the REPL (in linux i would type 'fg' to bring the paused program in to the foreground).

i have tried 'reset' (to reset terminal settings) before hitting 'fg' to bring the REPL back.  That did not help.

The work around is just to restart the REPL or use another window, but this is annoying if screen real estate is limited, and also when the REPL takes a while to initialize.     Anyone know of a good trick to make this work ?   Thanks!